# Why is the position vector invariant under time reversal?

Tags: time-reversal-symmetry

I'm pretty sure I'm misinterpreting something, but my reasoning for why it is not is that when you reverse time, the trajectory in which $x$ follows, namely $x(t)$, changes direction, so that at any given nonzero time {$t_0 | t_0 \ne 0$},
$$x(t_0) \ne x(-t_0)$$ in general.

Comment: A very absurd example: London is still London if the time runs backwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That argument is correct, but it applies to a *trajectory*, which is a function mapping times to position vectors. A single position vector itself, something like $(-5,2,3)$, is not associated with time in any way, and when you reverse time, it doesn't change the point that is labeled by those coordinates.

Maybe this simplified example will help: consider a function $f(t) = t^2 + 2t$. The function itself is not time reversal invariant, because $f(t) \neq f(-t)$. But each possible *value* of the function *is* invariant. $5$ is not affected by taking $t\to -t$.